# The minimal volume of the intersection of two $\mathscr{l}_1$-ball in high dimension

Tags: analytic-number-theory, euclidean-geometry, vector-spaces, analytic-geometry

We define
$$B_1(r,c) = \{x\in\mathbb{R}^d : \Vert{}x-c\Vert_1 \le r\}$$

Now for arbitrary constant $r \ge s > 0$, given constant $\epsilon \in (r-s,r+s)$, considering $v \in \mathbb{R}^d$ such that $\Vert{v}\Vert_1 = \epsilon$,
what is the minimal volume of $B_1(r,0) \cap B_1(s,v)$ when $v$ varying?

Is there any idea or suggested reference?

I am sure that it goes to minimal when $v = (\epsilon, 0, ..., 0)$
after considering situations where $d = 2, 3$.
But have no idea for strict proof.
Any idea for proof?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Isn't it just a straightforward application of Brunn-Minkowski?

Comment: Done. $\hspace{5pt}$

Answer (score 3):

Let $v=v_1\varepsilon e_1+\dots + v_d\varepsilon e_d$ where $\sum_i |v_i|=1$ and the directions of the coordinate vectors $e_j$ are chosen so that $v_j\ge 0$. Then for any convex body $K$, 
$$
\sum_i v_i (B_1(s,\varepsilon e_i)\cap K)\subset B_1(s,v)\cap K
$$ 
where the sum on the left is understood in the Minkowski sense. Thus, by BM, we have 
$$
|B_1(s,v)\cap K|\ge \min_j |B_1(s,\varepsilon e_j)\cap K|
$$
When $K=B_1(r,0)$, all volumes in the minimum are the same and equal to your conjectured minimum. That's all.

Comment: @nowhere Yes, it is. Wikipedia gives you the version for 2 bodies (in the bottom section) but the generalization to any finite number of bodies is straightforward.