# Minimum volume of intersection between two high-dim $\ell^1$-balls

Tags: convex-geometry, geometry

Let $B_1$ and $B_2$ be two balls with the same radius, in $\mathbb R^n$ with the $\ell^1$ norm. The distance between the centers of $B_1$ and $B_2$ is $d(B_1, B_2)$. Is there any deterministic method or probabilistic method to calculate the minimum volume of $B_1 \cap B_2$?

Comment: Distance in what norm?

Comment: I will point out that the (geometry) tag is deprecated - see [the tag-info](https://mathoverflow.net/tags/geometry/info). (However, I'll leave the choice of a suitable geometry-related [top-level tags](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1457/why-are-mo-tags-formatted-as-they-are) to more experienced users.)

Comment: What is the meaning of "minimum volume" here? Minimum with respect to different radius balls?

Comment: $L_1$, $L_2$, or $L_{infinity}$

Comment: The distance can be $L_1$ or $L_2$. The two balls have the same radius. Given the fixed distance, the two balls can have different overlaps. The aim is to find the minimum overlap between the two balls.

Comment: The $\ell^1$ distance has been discussed at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/331980/the-minimal-volume-of-the-intersection-of-two-mathscrl-1-ball-in-high-dimen/332025#332025 The other two cases look more interesting.

Comment: The result of $l_1$ distance looks really interesting. Could you provide more details (e.g., in terms of what theorem or proof) about the inequality $$
\sum_i v_i (B_1(s,\varepsilon e_i)\cap K)\subset B_1(s,v)\cap K
$$